# I can't post a certain string of Arabic text here

Tags: bug, status-completed, validation

I am trying to post a bug report here that contains some Arabic text (it's an RTL issue). You can read the text of the bug report at this pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HCUHQdb8.

When I do so, I get one of those red boxes at the right side of the textarea that tells me my post cannot be submitted. You can read the text of that red box at this pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NT83uzFv. (Pastebin links so I don't trip the validator in *this* post, of course.)

I can't read Arabic, so I don't know what the problematic string says (though a helpful anonymous editor informs me that it says: "Hakeem/Hakim the lost Philosopher"), but I don't see any reason why any particular string of Arabic text would be excluded by the validation machinery.

In case this is a client-side issue - I'm using Chrome 35 on Windows 7.

Comment: Seems weird. I can't read, but a few translations say it's the word 'sage' or 'wise'.

Comment: @justcool393 You're doing very well for someone who can't read!

Comment: Don't worry, I knew what you meant, I just couldn't resist ;)

Comment: There were a few instances where SE put the whole arabic alphabet into the blacklist to fight spam waves. But this was always just a short-term solution and should not be active anymore.

Comment: Hm. [Here's a post](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/13297/4813) over at [islam.se] from 2 days ago that seems to have had no problem with Arabic text (though maybe none of the characters in that post were among the ones I tried to use?).

Comment: @MadScientist It's still active on Drupal Answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this is a blast from the past. About a year ago [this happened](http://www.redorbit.com/news/technology/1112936021/unicode-of-death-brings-down-os-x-ios-083013/), and we ended up blacklisting Arabic characters on a number of sites, most notably [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com). There may have also been a troll or two who kept making posts to trigger the vulnerability? I forget the specifics now.

Either way, it looks like that blacklist entry survived up until now here on MSE. I removed it. Let me know if you still have problems posting.

Comment: I was able to post [the bug report that triggered this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233620/224428), so I suppose that did it. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but while trying to post on http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com I ran into a blacklisted Chinese character. If so, please lift the ban so that esolangs involving Chinese characters can be used properly. http://i.imgur.com/XUcny8L.png

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a legitimate rejection on the server-side validator.  It's literally handing back this JSON to inform us what the error is:

```
{"success":false,"errors":{"Body":["Body cannot contain \"<REDACTED>\"."]}}
```

It *feels* like a bug, but it could also be the case that Stack Exchange hasn't had a need to support this sort of text before.

If we try with a single character, the validation still fails. It could be the case that the validator just doesn't support those characters.