# RTL issue with Arabic text in closed-as-duplicate banner

Tags: bug, rtl

[User 85969 at Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/85969/85969) has a username consisting of Arabic script:

```
حكيم الفيلسوف الضائع
```

This user participated in the closure of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/817268/49701), resulting in the following notice being displayed (back when the closure was one hour old):

[image]

The "1" in "1 hour ago" seems to have been displaced. (Note: the issue is not present at this point, since the notice is now sufficiently old that it reads "marked as duplicate by [...] Jun 1 at 20:55", rather than using a relative date.)

This might be a duplicate of [Please add Right To Left text support in Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5303/224428); I'm not really sure.